# how i can take user input supposedly a link to a pict and assing it into pict src attribute when the use click a button

Tags: javascript

I want the user to put a link to a picture and click the button and that will make the picture change into the one the user add

```
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="lights" id="imageToChange" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="text" id="imageInput" />
        <button id="btn-changeImage">Change Image</button>
      </div>


  </body>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is the js code that I tried

```
const changeImageBtn = document.getElementById("btn-changeImage");// select "change image" button (querySelector)
const changeImageF = () => {


   var value = document.getElementById('imageInput')
   document.getElementById('imageToChange').src=value;
}

changeImageBtn.addEventListener("click", changeImageF());
```

Answer (score 0):

Good attempt, you were almost there.

The first thing I noticed was that the js code ran when the page is loaded, so it made the picture blank instantly. To prevent this, try using an onclick attribute for the button, or add an event listener like i did below.

```
var value = document.getElementById('imageInput')
```

Also, the above line only retrieves the element, so add '.value' to the end to receive the value of the text box.

I've written a working version below.

```
const changeImageBtn = document.getElementById("btn-changeImage");

changeImageBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var value = document.getElementById('imageInput').value;
  document.getElementById('imageToChange').setAttribute('src',value);       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.getElementById('imageInput')` you'll get the whole Html Element but you just want to get the input text.

change that line to `document.getElementById('imageInput').value`

you also have a small syntax error on the click event listener it should be `changeImageBtn.addEventListener("click", () => changeImageF());`

Comment: appreciate it. that made since.